# I need to extract id from th class text

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have the HTML code below:

```
<div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-xl-4 product type-product post-31121 status-publish first instock product_cat-tyres has-post-thumbnail purchasable product-type-simple">
<div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-xl-4 product type-product post-31301 status-publish instock product_cat-tyres has-post-thumbnail purchasable product-type-simple">
<div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-xl-4 product type-product post-28416 status-publish last instock product_cat-tyres has-post-thumbnail purchasable product-type-simple">
```

I need to extract the Id of each product presented in the class description using beatiful soup (**31121**/ **31301**/ **28416** are the ids)
how can i do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iterate over your selection extract `class` attribute, iterate over its classes and pick `class` starts with `post-`:

```
[c.split('-')[-1] for e in soup.select('div.type-product') for c in e['class'] if c.startswith('post-')]
```

or

```
[c.split('-')[-1] for e in soup.select('div[class*="post-"]') for c in e['class'] if c.startswith('post-')]
```

#### Example

```
html = '''
<div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-xl-4 product type-product post-31121 status-publish first instock product_cat-tyres has-post-thumbnail purchasable product-type-simple">
<div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-xl-4 product type-product post-31301 status-publish instock product_cat-tyres has-post-thumbnail purchasable product-type-simple">
<div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-xl-4 product type-product post-28416 status-publish last instock product_cat-tyres has-post-thumbnail purchasable product-type-simple">
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

[c.split('-')[-1] for e in soup.select('div.type-product') for c in e['class'] if c.startswith('post-')]
```

#### output

```
['31121', '31301', '28416']
```

Answer (score 1):

- Select all the div's that starts with post-.
- Iterate all the class names of that div to filter out the classname which starts with post-.
- add post id to the list.

---

```
import re

html_attr='''
<div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-xl-4 product type-product post-31121 status-publish first instock product_cat-tyres has-post-thumbnail purchasable product-type-simple">
<div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-xl-4 product type-product post-31301 status-publish instock product_cat-tyres has-post-thumbnail purchasable product-type-simple">
<div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-xl-4 product type-product post-28416 status-publish last instock product_cat-tyres has-post-thumbnail purchasable product-type-simple">'''

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_attr, 'html.parser')
div_list = soup.find_all('div', {"class": re.compile("^post-")})
id_list = []
for div in div_list:
    post_id = [name.split('-')[1] for name in div['class'] if name.startswith('post-')][0]
    id_list.append(post_id)

print(id_list)
```

**Output**

```
['31121', '31301', '28416']
```